# Particular property of $p$-norm with $1<p\le 2$

Tags: proof-writing, lp-spaces

Let $1<p\le 2$ and $q=p/(p-1)$. Let $u\in L_p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu).$ I must prove that $$\|u\|_p^q=\||u|^q\|_{p-1},$$ where $$\|u\|_p:=\left(\int_X |u|^p\,d\mu\right)^\frac{1}{p}.$$

**Question.** After several attempts I was unable to show this. Could someone show me the way??

Comment: The RHS should be to the power of $(p-1)$

Comment: Your edited question follows from the previous version of my answer by raising both sides to the power $q/p$, which I've added to the answer anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be obvious:$$ \|u\|_{L^p}^p = \| |u|^p \|_{L^1}.$$
Using this twice,
$$ \|u\|_{L^p}^p = \| |u|^{q(p/q)} \|_{L^1}=\| |u|^q \|^{p/q}_{L^{p/q}}.$$
Raise both sides to the power $q/p$ and we get
$$ \|u\|_{L^p}^q = \|  |u|^q\|_{L^{p/q}} $$
Now we just use
$$ p/q = p-1$$
to see that
$$ \|u\|_{L^p}^q = \| |u|^q \|_{L^{p-1}}.$$
(BTW its obvious where $p\neq 1$ is needed, but I don't see where $p<2$ is needed. Indeed, if we instead impose $p\ge 2$ then we obtain actual norms on the right, since $p-1\ge 1$.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: note that:
$$||u|^q|^{p-1} = |u|^{q(p-1)} = |u|^p$$